# AS3 as vs Class()

Tags: actionscript-3, class, casting

I don't fully understand the advantages/disadvantages between these two methods of typecasting in this example:

```
for each(var i:DisplayObject in _display)
{
    trace(i as Sprite);
    trace(Sprite(i));
}
```

Is there a recommendation around this at all? I've always wrapped in `Class()` like the latter example but `as` sometimes reads more easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what I understand, the difference is `TypeError`.

```
var o:Object = "test";

trace( o as MovieClip ); // displays: null
trace ( MovieClip ( o ) ); // generates a TypeError
```

http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/actionscript-3-casting.html

Answer (score 0):

I always use as, because some Classes have unexpected results when you use Class(reference).  For instance

```
var arr:Array = [1, 2, 3];

var arr2:Array = Array(arr);
```

arr2 is now [[1,2,3]]

This is fairly obvious when arr and arr2 are defined right there together, but when arr is defined somewhere else and you don't know whether it contains an array or not you can get a bug using the Array(arr) syntax.